# Nodegit: How to modify a file and push the changes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, nodegit

Looked around for an example, but couldn't find one. The documentation is not explained and I could not figure it out.

How to modify a file (README.md for example), create a commit for the modified file and then push the commit to the server ?

Nodegit: http://www.nodegit.org/

Nodegit documentation: http://www.nodegit.org/nodegit

Comment: I am currently trying to figure this out too. That documenation is really vague and API not really that helpful. I suspect there will be `repo.createCommit` method involved somehow, but it's really confusing. Did you found anything on this ?

Comment: Oh, I have totally missed this, very useful examples ... https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/tree/master/example

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is an example of how to create/add and commit on their repo, which can help you with the modifying the file.

https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/blob/master/examples/add-and-commit.js

Regarding the commit and push, here is the snippet of how my code looks like and i hope it helps you a bit. It took me quite a bit to figure this out and thanks to the guys on [Gitter](https://gitter.im/nodegit/nodegit), i finaly found an answer.

The code look like this:

```js
var path = require('path');

var nodegit = require('nodegit'),
    repoFolder = path.resolve(__dirname, 'repos/test/.git'),
    fileToStage = 'README.md';

var repo, index, oid, remote;

nodegit.Repository.open(repoFolder)
  .then(function(repoResult) {
    repo = repoResult;
    return repoResult.openIndex();
  })
  .then(function(indexResult) {
    index  = indexResult;

    // this file is in the root of the directory and doesn't need a full path
    index.addByPath(fileToStage);

    // this will write files to the index
    index.write();

    return index.writeTree();
  })
  .then(function(oidResult) {
    oid = oidResult;

    return nodegit.Reference.nameToId(repo, 'HEAD');
  })
  .then(function(head) {
    return repo.getCommit(head);
  })
  .then(function(parent) {
    author = nodegit.Signature.now('Author Name', 'author@email.com');
    committer = nodegit.Signature.now('Commiter Name', 'commiter@email.com');

    return repo.createCommit('HEAD', author, committer, 'Added the Readme file for theme builder', oid, [parent]);
  })
  .then(function(commitId) {
    return console.log('New Commit: ', commitId);
  })

  /// PUSH
  .then(function() {
    return repo.getRemote('origin');
  })
  .then(function(remoteResult) {
    console.log('remote Loaded');
    remote = remoteResult;
    remote.setCallbacks({
      credentials: function(url, userName) {
        return nodegit.Cred.sshKeyFromAgent(userName);
      }
    });
    console.log('remote Configured');

    return remote.connect(nodegit.Enums.DIRECTION.PUSH);
  })
  .then(function() {
    console.log('remote Connected?', remote.connected())

    return remote.push(
      ['refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master'],
      null,
      repo.defaultSignature(),
      'Push to master'
    )
  })
  .then(function() {
    console.log('remote Pushed!')
  })
  .catch(function(reason) {
    console.log(reason);
  })
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tried to edit the post but it won't let me - there's a missing " on the line: `nodegit.Signature.now("Commiter Name", "commiter@email.com");`

Comment: Can you clarify how much of this is needed if I just want to do this equivalent of "git commit -am <msg>"?  I'm just trying to call repo.createCommitOnHead without adding any (new?) files and it never returns.

Comment: Even when I do exactly as it says, it gets to the createCommit call, and that never completes.

Answer (score 2):

Rafael's solution works for sure although I might add that there is no needed to perform a `.connect` into the server. Here is a minimal approach on pushing a repo:

- Pushing to *master* using only username and password authentication:

  ```
          //Previous calls

          }).then(function() {
              return repo.getRemote("origin"); //Get origin remote
          }).then(function(remote) {
              return remote.push(["refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master"], {
                  callbacks: {
                      credentials: function(url, userName) {
                          console.log("Requesting creds");

                          return NodeGit.Cred.userpassPlaintextNew("[USERNAME]", "[PASSWORD]");
                      }
                  }
              });
          }).then(function(err) {
              console.log("Push error number:");
              console.log(err);
          }).catch(function(err) {
              console.log(err);
          }).done(function(commitId) {
              console.log("All done");
          })
  ```
- Pushing to *myBranch* over SSH auth:

  ```
          //Previous calls

          }).then(function() {
              return repo.getRemote("origin"); //Get origin remote
          }).then(function(remote) {
              return remote.push(["refs/heads/myBranch:refs/heads/myBranch"], {
                  callbacks: {
                      credentials: function(url, userName) {
                          console.log("Requesting creds");
                          return NodeGit.Cred.sshKeyFromAgent(userName);
                      }
                  }
              });
          }).then(function(err) {
              console.log("Push error number:");
              console.log(err);
          }).catch(function(err) {
              console.log(err);
          }).done(function(commitId) {
              console.log("All done");
          })
  ```