# git push remote ssh using Nodegit, Not working?

Tags: node.js, git, ssh, nodegit, node-github

Hi I am trying to do a `git push origin master` command with the help of `Nodegit`, but it is resulting in an error,

```
var Git = require('nodegit');
function gitRemoteLookUp(repoPath) {
var open = Git.Repository.open;
var Remote = Git.Remote;    
open(repoPath).then(function(repo){
    return Remote.lookup(repo, "origin");
}).then(function(remote){       
    var ref = "refs/heads/master:remotes/origin/master";                
    var firstPass = true;
    var options = {
      callbacks: {
        credentials: function(url, userName) {
          if (firstPass) {
            firstPass = false;
            if (url.indexOf("https") === -1) {                  
              return Git.Cred.sshKeyFromAgent('XYZ');
            } else {                    
                return Git.Cred.userpassPlaintextNew('XYZ', "XYZ");
            }
          } else {
            return Git.Cred.defaultNew();
          }
        },
        certificateCheck: function() {
          return 1;
        }
      }
    };
    return remote.push(ref, options);
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
})
}
```

I am using our internal ssh github server, which from the git Bash, for each push is asking for Username and Password.

Hence in hence in the code I have used the similar example as mentioned in the [github site](https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/blob/master/examples/push.js) and also in the [test site](https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/blob/master/test/tests/remote.js).

Pls help on this !!!!!!

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: [Error: Request failed with status code: 401] 
I am getting this error

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer to my own question,

The confusion lies in the SSH server and generic server,

i found two awesome post in the past nodegit questions,

```
var remote;
var repository;
function gitRemoteLookUp(repoPath) {
    var open = Git.Repository.open;     
    open(repoPath).then(function(repo){
        repository = repo;
        return repo.getRemote('origin');
    }).then(function(remoteResult){
        remote = remoteResult;          
        remote.setCallbacks({
              credentials: function(url, userName) {
                  // return Git.Cred.sshKeyFromAgent(userName);
                  return Git.Cred.userpassPlaintextNew('XYZ', "XYZ");
              }
          });


        return remote.connect(Git.Enums.DIRECTION.PUSH);
    }).then(function() {
      console.log('remote Connected?', remote.connected())

      return remote.push(
                ["refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master"],
                null,
                repository.defaultSignature(),
                "Push to master")
    }).then(function() {
        console.log('remote Pushed!')
    })
    .catch(function(reason) {
        console.log(reason);
    });
}
```

The main issue lies in configuring the credentials in the Nodegit Library.
Pls be careful in checking whether it is a SSH key based push or whether it works well with generic userpassPainTestNow mode. I have commented both the scenarios out there. These links turned out to be really useful for troubleshooting this.
[Nodegit: How to modify a file and push the changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23870374/nodegit-how-to-modify-a-file-and-push-the-changes)
https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/issues/463