# Nodegit create remote repository and make first push

Tags: node.js, github, nodegit

Many people claim to have solved this problem in the following examples

- https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/issues/463
- [Nodegit: How to modify a file and push the changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23870374/nodegit-how-to-modify-a-file-and-push-the-changes)

However after testing these solutions out I'm given an error that claims the `remote.setCallbacks(...)` function is undefined. A quick check at the Nodegit API documentation

- http://www.nodegit.org/api/remote/#push

confirms that the `remote.setCallbacks(...)` function is indeed undefined. I tried this example code found on the Nodegit page

- https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/blob/master/examples/push.js

But this code freezes at the `remote.push(...)` command. How have people managed to actually push code to a remote repository using Nodegit? Any help on the issue I've found thus far has been a disappointment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I was shooting myself in the foot all day. The reason the example code found at

- https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/blob/master/examples/push.js

wasn't working was because the remote github repository wasn't created before running the code. I'm guessing execution froze at the `remote.push(...)` command because the push prompt would make a request for the repository and not get a valid response, at which point it would make another request but still not get a valid response. Over and over again this would continue. The nodegit promise chain needs to establish a connection with the remote repository before it can finish. Unfortunately the Nodegit API documentation lacks explanation for many offered functions. Oh well, the important thing is a solution was reached!

Comment: I'm having the same problem as you. Are you saying the `examples/push.js` file in the NodeGit repo is incorrect?

Comment: It seems to be a half-truth for how to push to a remote git repo. `examples/push.js` seems to work for all pushes after the initial push which I carried out via the command line. `examples/push.js` seems to have trouble carrying out the `-u` option in a `git push -u origin master` call